# How Xamarin.Forms adjusts iOS/Android native elements (auto)height/width?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, custom-renderer

This is a general question and specific one.
For general purpose - **to understand how XF works** and specifically - for using in my custom controls.

So, the thing is that I should put the elements (generated by XF for specific system (iOS or Android)) into some custom place within `custom renderer`.

In a nutshell, it's embedding XF controls into native interface, in more details I need to put the controls into custom alert/popup.
The issue is that the final size of the elements (views) can be different from initially generated XF ones.
So I need further adjustment of them (for instance, to fit parent view bounds (as again, the parent size is custom one and usually platform-dependent and screen-size-dependent)).

Let's say, I have:

```
    <controls:AlertPanel 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

where AlertPanel is:

```
    public class AlertPanel : Frame
```

inside of the custom renderer (of the AlertPanel for iOS):

```
    // container is my native (manually created) view
    container.AddSubview(this);
```

and `this` is the renderer class (inherited basically from UIView).

But if I do this right on `IsVisible` attribute setting to `true` (and the whole UI control block is dynamically created (or at least positioned)), the bounds setup via:

```
    this.Frame = new CGRect(...);
```

... doesn't quite properly reflect what I expect.

It's much better when I apply that **after** (for instance) 10 ms **delay**, however, this is neither nice approach, nor having clear understanding of which way this all works.

In addition, I haven't found any constrains applied to the view generated by XF, so I am considering the bounds are strictly defined or calculated dynamically.

Any clues?

Comment: Where do you place the `container`? You want the XF's controls wrapped by the `container`? You'd better share a sample to help us 
understand your requirements and reproduce your issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've already provided the details. I cannot have the XF in place, and the way I wrap it is above: `container.AddSubview(this);`, where `container` is any other (my custom) UIView.